Correct value category for standalone function argument(s)
I want to provide to my Rational type a generic constructor that accepts a couple of generic arguments (constrained by a concept), so I can avoid to write dozens of different constructors for Natural, Integer, Real, Irrational, Complex and its possible different combinations.
So I wrote something like this:
template<Numerical L, Numerical R>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr Rational(const L&& numerator, const R&& denominator) noexcept
    : _numerator(static_cast<Integer>(std::forward<L>(numerator))),
      _denominator(static_cast<Integer>(std::forward<R>(denominator))) {}

Notes:

_numerator and _denominator are Integer types, which is an strong type for int
It took me a while to figure out why I shouldn't be taking rvalue references by const.

So, I remove the const and after spot that there's some places in my code where I was using lvalue (const) references (so I had to add the qualifier removers type traits provided by the standard) everything works. But now, I don't know what should be the correct approach for such constructor.
Since Numerical is a concept like this:
    template <typename T>
    concept Number = ((
        std::is_same_v<T, Natural> ||
        std::is_same_v<T, Integer> ||
        std::is_same_v<T, Rational> ||
        std::is_same_v<T, Irrational> ||
        std::is_same_v<T, Real> ||
        std::is_same_v<T, Complex>
    ) && requires {
        T::symbol;  /* Check if 'T' has a static member named 'symbol' */
        { T::symbol } -> std::same_as<const MathSymbol&>;  // Check if 'T::symbol' has the type MathSymbol
    } );

    // Helper to remove const, volatile, and reference qualifiers
    template<typename T>
    using remove_cvref_t = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

    template <typename T>
    concept Numerical = Number<remove_cvref_t<T>> || std::is_arithmetic_v<remove_cvref_t<T>>;


So, after some tests, since most of the types are primitives or my strong types, maybe the correct approach should be take them always by value, but here's the thing. I am not sure.
It's is possible to have good advice and/or a general rule of thumb of when I should be taking my args by value, by lvalue reference or by rvalue reference (Scott Meyers universal reference) depending on my APIs?
PD: Is just a feeling, but I see the universal references a lot of overkill for my API, but I would like to know in which scenario cases they are really useful.

Your Number concept is strange; you restrict it to a specific set of types (and not in a concept-friendly way), then ... check a property of the type?  Each of those types have ::symbol that is const MathSymbol& or they don't, the truth of that is independent of T.

Second, if you have arbitrary precision values, copying them could be expensive (are you using copy on write?); if you know that copying and moving is cheap for all of your types, then there is no reason to use universal references, just take by value or by non-const reference (depending on if it is an in or an in-out parameter).  Universal references are usually used in a context where the argument may be copied or moved conditionally depending on l/r value category of the argument: if both copy and move are cheap, there is no need to use them.

Now, that isn't the only use; another use of universal reference is in binding type code.  Like std::bind or similar, where the r/l value-ness of the argument changes how the code works.  However, usually you are better off following the std::async playbook here, and using std::ref for explicit out-references, as implicit reference binding is pretty dangerous.

Aside std::remove_cvref_t is older than concepts, you don't need to define it yourself

If you are going to static cast to Integer, why is this constructor a template? I would be really surprised when I make a Rational out of two Complexs, and the result is nothing like A / B

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am curious about why not const l-value references. They are never out parameters. I think that they are pretty cheap to copy/move (they are mostly wrappers over integers or doubles). Well, maybe double isn't as cheap as int, but primitives. But you didn't mention const l-value refs. There's a reason for that?

@Caleth I am missing a lot of implementation details about rationals, and Real and Complex aren't even writen yet. I think that the point is to pass (I insist, for the moment) any Natural, Integer or primitive. So I don't see how can I accept any of those without a template, because I want to avoid at all cost to use accesors on client's side, or do static_cast or anything. The API should consume any Numerical, in a safe-controlled way, making the call site as clean as possible

@AlexVergara A const l value ref is useful if your data is expensive to copy, and the code wants to look at it but probably not copy it.  If the data is cheap to copy, then taking by value removes the non-local state from your function body.  (As an example, you pass a struct value to a function by const&; in the function, it decides the struct needs invalidation, and changes the value in the struct.  Now the value passed to the function has changed.  In 99/100 cases this is surprising and this can cause significant and bad bugs.)

@AlexVergara if everything "below" Integer implicitly converts to Integer, then you only need Rational::Rational(Integer n, Integer d), and the call site is still clean. If you don't want any implicit conversions, then yes you need a template, but not Numerical, you'll need a concept Integral too.

I'd also recommend normalising _numerator and _denominator, in the same way the members of std::ratio

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont sorry, I am not getting that example. If I pass by const&, how can I change the value in the struct within the function that took the struct by const&? I am sure that I've missed something

@Caleth ahh, my bad. Maybe I should've noted that. implicit conversions are completely prohibited in our codebase. And yes, I'll plan to have more concepts like Numerical in future iterations, but refactoring the members into one single standalone template resolved by adl is being enought for the moment! :) And also yes, I already have my ratio type ready, but I wasn't unsure if it would fit later into more abstract mathematical definitions (like group theory and so on). But thanks for pointing that out

struct foo { int x; int y; foo(); }; class mine { foo f; void do_something(int const& input) { if (input!=f.x) { f = {}; f.x = input; } };  mine m; m.do_something(m.f.x); - boom, modified the input value "accidentally" in the middle of do_something.  References are pointers, and dereferencing pointers accesses global state.  (I had real production code crash this way - in its case, we had an optional<String> that got reset in the middle of some method, and we where passing it into a chain of functions as const& String.  The result was a dangling String reference...

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont ahhh, now I've got it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Pass by value vs pass by rvalue reference looks related, even though that question specifically excludes templates. Preventing non-const lvalues from resolving to rvalue reference instead of const lvalue reference might cover what you were trying to solve originally.
